# Flutter : Display data in listview with static string and scrollable array

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My data is like this:

[image: Data]

I want to display it like this:

[image: dynamic item]

In the example, the title and subtitle are static. But in my case, it is dynamic. How do I achieve this UI? I tried like putting it in a `ListView.builder` with horizontal scrolling. But again do I need another `ListView.builder` to show restaurant list from rests array? Or any other ways to do this?

Comment: you're not asking a question but asking to create whole functionality :(

Comment: could you please include your code too?

Answer (score 0):

*That can depend on your layout.*

**You can look at the use case below.**

**Using ListView + ListView:**

*If you want to give your second ListView full height.*

```
ListView(
  children: [
    // Other widgets ...
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true, //    <-- Set this to true
      physics: ScrollPhysics(), // <-- Also change physics
      itemBuilder: ...,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

YES; You can use listview to implement this functionality.

```
demo(){
    List<Map> restaurantArray = [
      {"name":"breakfase 1","cover":"http://......."},
      {"name":"breakfase 2","cover":"http://......."},
      {"name":"breakfase 3","cover":"http://......."},
      {"name":"breakfase 4","cover":"http://......."},
      {"name":"breakfase 5","cover":"http://......."},
    ];
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: restaurantArray.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx,index){
          // return your cell with data
          return Container(
            child: Text(restaurantArray[index]["name"].toString()),
          );
        }
    );
}
```